# Flink Count of Events using metric

Tags: stream, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a topic in kafka where i am getting multiple type of events in json format. I have created a filestreamsink to write these events to  S3 with bucketing.

```
FlinkKafkaConsumer errorTopicConsumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer(ERROR_KAFKA_TOPICS,
                new SimpleStringSchema(),
                properties);
        final StreamingFileSink<Object> errorSink = StreamingFileSink
                .forRowFormat(new Path(outputPath + "/error"), new SimpleStringEncoder<>("UTF-8"))
                .withBucketAssigner(new EventTimeBucketAssignerJson())
                .build();

        env.addSource(errorTopicConsumer)
                .name("error_source")
                .setParallelism(1)
                .addSink(errorSink)
                .name("error_sink").setParallelism(1);
```

```
public class EventTimeBucketAssignerJson implements BucketAssigner<Object, String> {

    @Override
    public String getBucketId(Object record, Context context) {
        StringBuffer partitionString = new StringBuffer();
        Tuple3<String, Long, String> tuple3 = (Tuple3<String, Long, String>) record;
        try {
            partitionString.append("event_name=")
                    .append(tuple3.f0).append("/");

            String timePartition = TimeUtils.getEventTimeDayPartition(tuple3.f1);
            partitionString.append(timePartition);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            partitionString.append("year=").append(Constants.DEFAULT_YEAR).append("/")
                    .append("month=").append(Constants.DEFAULT_MONTH).append("/")
                    .append("day=").append(Constants.DEFAULT_DAY);
        }
        return partitionString.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public SimpleVersionedSerializer<String> getSerializer() {
        return SimpleVersionedStringSerializer.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

Now i want to publish hourly count of each event as metrics to prometheus and publish a grafana dashboard over that.

So please help me how can i achieve hourly count for each event using flink metrics and publish to prometheus.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Normally, this is done by simply creating a counter for requests and then using the `rate()` function in Prometheus, this will give you the rate of requests in the given time.

If You, however, want to do this on Your own for some reason, then You can do something similar to what has been done in `org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.stats.Rate`. So You would, in this case, need to gather list of samples with the time at which they were collected, along with the window size You want to use for calculation of the rate, then You could simply do the calculation, i.e. remove samples that went out of scope and has expired and then simply calculate how many samples are in the window.

You could then set the `Gauge` to the calculated value.

Comment: Thanks dominik. As you mentioned creating counter but thr problem is i want seperate count for each event type. So in my data there is field called event_name and i want count corresponding to each event.

Comment: Technically, You could simply create a Map with Counter per EventType and increment them for each event.

Comment: I could not get you completely. Can you please provide a sample code.